# Spring Elasticsearch reindex method

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I've written a reindex method that does the following:

```
public void reindex() {
    IndexOperations indexOperations = elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(Song.class);
    List<Song> songs = songRepository.findAll();
    songSearchRepository.deleteAll();
    indexOperations.delete();
    indexOperations.create();
    songSearchRepository.saveAll(songs);
}
```

It does the job but I'm now sure whether it makes sence just to delete and then create an index. How can I improve this method?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I don't see the point in reindexing to the same index.

If you want to reindex to a different index, you should use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/docs-reindex.html) of Elasticsearch. This is not yet supported directly in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

To reindex to a different index using Spring Data Elasticsearch you should use paged queries in a loop to read from one index and write the data to the second index.

**Edit 16.10.2020:**

Don't use copying in a loop as I suggested, like @joeyave commented, the indices can get out of sync here.

I created [an issue in Spring Data Elasticsearch Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-955) to have reindex support implemented.

Comment: Index can get out of sync.